# SQL Query to find Duplicate email under different ID

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql

I am trying to run a SQL to get a list of Distinct email ID.

For example if the

```
John Does john@somebody.com

Jane Doe john@somebody.com

Alice J mary@abc.com
```

I want my output to have only

```
Jane Doe john@somebody.com

Alice J mary@abc.com
```

My current query says

```
SELECT distinct
Account.Email AS Email,
Account.FirstName,
Account.LastName
```

But I noticed that there are duplicate emails in my output.

Thanks
Esha

Comment: Does this answer your question? [De-duplicating emails before send](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/340947/de-duplicating-emails-before-send)

Answer (score 3):

Try this, it will group all your contacts by email and pick the top values for first and last name along with each email address:

```
SELECT Email,
MAX(FirstName) AS FirstName,
MAX(LastName) AS LastName
FROM /*data extension name*/
GROUP BY Email
```

In above script, replace `/*data extension name*/` with the actual name of your DE that you are using to pull data from. If your Data Extension name has any spaces or special characters, wrap it in square brackets `[DE name]`.